# How to set the Android version to use in Delphi X6?

Tags: android, delphi, sdk, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I use Delphi XE6 to develop Android Apps but they are not working on older phones. I get the message `Not Supported` when trying to install.

I believe it is because this version of Delphi comes with pre-configured NDK and SDK for 4.4 KitKat.

My question is how to properly configure Delphi to develop with 2.2 or 2.3 version of Android?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Adding_an_Android_SDK)

Comment: @KenWhite The SDK version does not determine the API level of the generated APK. I tried to find documentation on how to set the (minimum) supported target API level but could not find it. I assume the Delphi generated APK file targets Android 2.3 (API Level 10) for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Android 2.2 is unsupported, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development

> RAD Studio supports development on ARMv7 devices that run the
>   following versions of the Android operating system:

```
KitKat             Android 4.4                 API Level 19
Jelly Bean         Android 4.1.x, 4.2.x, 4.3.x API Levels 16, 17, 18
Ice Cream Sandwich Android 4.0.3 and 4.0.4     API Level 15
Gingerbread        Android 2.3.3 – 2.3.7       API Level 10
```

I assume the Delphi generated APK file targets Android 2.3 (API Level 10) for maximum compatibility.

Comment: I tested on a 2.3.6 XT305 Motorola and it was not supported :-(

Comment: @EASI [Android Hardware Requirements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development#Android_Hardware_Requirements): ARM Cortex-A series, ARMv7 Instructions, NEON Technology, GPU